Relation between specific heats for a magnetic system
I have been trying to prove the relations between specific heats at constant magnetization and magnetic field H, i.e. $C_H$ and $C_M$. I know that the relationship between $C_V$ and $C_V$ is given as $$\kappa_T (C_P-C_V) = TV\alpha_P^2$$ and I want to prove similar relations for magnetic systems. Problem is, I have been stuck at it for the past two days and am getting increasingly exasperated.
How do I go about doing this? No matter what I try, I end up getting stuck somewhere. My starting point is to write entropy as $S\equiv S(T,V,M)$ but even that leaves me nowhere.
Is there a source I can refer to that lists out the correct formulae for the four thermodynamic potentials in a magnetic system. I know that $dU=TdS-PdV+HdM$, and I want to find such equations for all thermodynamic potentials.

I believe that research in the direction of the magnetocaloric effect gives something, for example https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.08347,   https://zaguan.unizar.es/record/9510/files/TESIS-2012-086.pdf

Neglecting pressure and volume, your energy is:
$$
dU=TdS+HdM
$$
You can therefore apply the same method by formally substituting $P\to-H$ and $V\to M$. The analogue for enthalpy is:
$$
\mathcal H = U-HM \\
d\mathcal H = TdS-MdH
$$
and define the respective heat capacities:
$$
C_M = \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_M \quad C_H = \left(\frac{\partial \mathcal H}{\partial T}\right)_H
$$
By analogy, you can immediately write Mayer’s relation:
$$
C_H-C_M=T\frac{\alpha^2}{\chi}\\
\alpha = \left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial T}\right)_H \quad \chi= \left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial H}\right)_T
$$
with $\chi$ magnetic susceptibility replacing compressibility and $\alpha$ magnetic "expansion" (there must be a more common name in the literature) replacing thermal expansion.
The proof is the same, the goal is to express $C_M$ in terms of $T,H$. You just need to use Maxwell's relation, i.e. the existence of state functions. For this, it is best to rewrite the expressions of heat capacities:
$$
C_M = T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_M \quad C_H = T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_H
$$
Using the chain rule:
$$
\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_M = \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_H+\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial H}\right)_T\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial T}\right)_M
$$
From Maxwell's relation on free enthalpy:
$$
G = \mathcal H-TS \quad dG = -SdT-MdH \\
\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial H}\right)_T = \left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial T}\right)_H
$$
Then, using:
$$
dM = \left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial T}\right)_HdT+\left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial H}\right)_TdH \\
\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial T}\right)_M = -\frac{\left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial T}\right)_H}{\left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial H}\right)_T}
$$
so you get:
$$
T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_M = T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_H-T\frac{\left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial T}\right)_H}{\left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial H}\right)_T}\left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial T}\right)_H
$$
Substituting the definition of the various coefficients, you recover Mayer's relation.

Thank you so much. That is a great answer. I think a major reason I was getting lost is the lack of correct definitions. For instance, I was able to arrive at partial M over partial T on the RHS. However, I was unaware that alpha is defined like that.
